Some incorrect terms in generalizing Bochner's Formula
I am interested in Bochner's Formula but for slightly more general applications. In particular, I am interested in $\Delta g(U,V)$ where $U$ and $V$ are vector fields on a manifold. This involves computing $\nabla \cdot (\nabla_U V)$ (where $\nabla \cdot$ denotes the divergence). I seem to be getting an unexpected sign at the end of the calculation, but I am not sure where the sign error is coming from.
Let $E_1,...,E_n$ be a local orthonornmal frame. Then,
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (\nabla_U V) = g(\nabla_{E_i}\nabla_U V,E_i).    
\end{equation}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation}
R(E_i,U)V = \nabla_{E_i}\nabla_U V-\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V - \nabla_{[E_i,U]}V.
\end{equation}
So (summation convention with the $i$s),
\begin{align}
\text{Ric}(U,V) &= g(R(E_i,U)V,E_i)\\
&= g(\nabla_{E_i}\nabla_U V,E_i)-g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i)-g(\nabla_{[E_i,U]}V,E_i)\\
&= \nabla \cdot(\nabla_U V) -g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i)-g(\nabla_{[E_i,U]}V,E_i).
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\nabla \cdot(\nabla_U V) = \text{Ric}(U,V) + g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i) + g(\nabla_{[E_i,U]}V,E_i).
\end{equation*}
Letting $V^{\flat} = i_V g$, we use an exterior derivative identity to compute
\begin{align*}
g(\nabla_{[E_i,U]}V,E_i) &= g(\nabla_{[E_i,U]}V,E_i) -g(\nabla_{E_i}V,[E_i,U]) + g(\nabla_{E_i}V,[E_i,U])\\
&= dV^{\flat}([E_i,U],E_i) + g(\nabla_{E_i}V,[E_i,U])\\
&= dV^{\flat}([E_i,U],E_i) + g(\nabla_{E_i}V,\nabla_{E_i}U-\nabla_{U}E_i)\\
&= dV^{\flat}([E_i,U],E_i) + g(\nabla_{E_i}U,\nabla_{E_i}V)-g(\nabla_{E_i}V,\nabla_{U}E_i)
\end{align*}
Therefore, the last two terms of $\nabla \cdot(\nabla_U V)$ combine as,
\begin{align*}
&g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i) + g(\nabla_{[E_i,U]}V,E_i)\\
&= g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i) + dV^{\flat}([E_i,U],E_i) + g(\nabla_{E_i}U,\nabla_{E_i}V)-g(\nabla_{E_i}V,\nabla_{U}E_i)\\
&= g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i) -g(\nabla_{E_i}V,\nabla_{U}E_i) + dV^{\flat}([E_i,U],E_i) + g(\nabla_{E_i}U,\nabla_{E_i}V).
\end{align*}
This final equation looks problematic to me. What I was expecting was the first terms to be
\begin{equation*}
g(\nabla_U \nabla_{E_i} V,E_i) + g(\nabla_{E_i}V,\nabla_{U}E_i) = U(g(\nabla_{E_i} V,E_i)) = g(U,\nabla (\nabla \cdot V)).
\end{equation*}
Of course, the result has to be consistent with Bochner's Formula, and substituting $V = \nabla u$, it looks like the only sign issue is the $(-)$ sign next to $g(\nabla_{E_i}V,\nabla_{U}E_i)$, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this sign.
Thanks for having a look!

Which Laplacian are you using?

I'm using $\Delta f = \nabla \cdot (\nabla f)$ (that is $\Delta f = - \delta df$).
